# php gettype fix

Tags: php, variables, sqlite, gettype

Following function I created is to store data in a database with the correct type.

I have several questions:

1. It makes sense to me to turn empty strings in to NULL. Are there consequences I am not considering?
2. What is a good max_length value for sqlite3 text. I know blob and text length constrains are the same, but are there any other considerations like displaying the data in a shell, etc.
3. Is there a simple way to check if data is an image, and what type, since mime is not available at this stage?
4. Does something stick out that I am missing?

   ```
   public static function getType($value, $max_length = 50){

       $type = gettype($value);

       if($type == 'NULL'
               || $type == 'boolean'
               || $type == 'integer'
               || $type == 'double'
               || $type == 'object'
               || $type == 'resource'
               || $type == 'array'
           )
           return array('type'=>$type,'value'=>$value);

       if($type == 'string' && empty($value))
           return array('type'=>'NULL','value'=>$value);

       if($type == 'string' && strlen($value) > $max_length)
           return array('type'=>'blob','value'=>$value);

       if($type == 'string' && substr($value, 0,1) === '0')
           return array('type'=>'string','value'=>$value);

       if($type == 'string' && is_numeric($value)){
           $int   = (int) $value;
           $float = (float) $value;

           if($int == $value){
               $value = $int;
               $type = 'integer';
           }elseif($float == $value){
               $value = $float;
               $type = 'double';
           }
       }elseif($type == 'string'){
           return array('type'=>$type,'value'=>$value);
       }else{
           $type = 'blob';
       }
       return array('type'=>$type,'value'=>$value);
   }
   ```

Comment: Minor quibble: `substr($value, 0,1) === 0` will probably never be true, should be `=== '0'`.

Comment: Sqlite is unknown terretory, but why would you need to know the type? Wouldn't Sqlite typecast it? Sounds a bit spaghetti to me if you don't allready know what type a specific variable is.

Comment: Thank you deceze, I overlooked that one

Comment: @Phliplip have you newer used php's gettype(). Without it you have to write a separate function for each type. Let's say you won't to store an image then you have to use a function that saves the image in the right place. If you get the type with gettype, you can have one function decide where to save the data based on the type.

Comment: You realize that usually everything coming from a database is a string in PHP? No matter if it just contains digits, binary data (image) or actual text.